# Windows Phone 8 scheduled task custom user control

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, lockscreen

I have successfully managed to implement lockscreen backgrounds into my WP8 application which uses a custom user control and render it as writeable bitmap since I want to have a dynamic lockscreen for example like a weather lockscreen.

I now want to implement a background task to generate this image and check for new weather data but I am unable to use the custom user control I created.

Is there a way I can use my user control in my background task? I have thought of creating a webservice that generates this image and simply the background task will call this service and just retrieve the image. but first I want to check if there is any way I can do it from within the app itself.

Comment: "I am unable to use the custom user control I created."  How so?

Comment: I can't use it from my background scheduled agent

Comment: why can't you use it from the background agent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess, given the information you've given: you can't use the usercontrol from the background agent's project because it's declared in the main project?

If so, all you have to do is to create a third project (of type "class library"). Move the usercontrol in that project, along with all the necessary dependencies. Then you can reference this third project from both the main project and the background agent's project.

Comment: hello, thank you, I am trying your method but I am facing one problem is that if lets say I put an image control in my usercontrol I cannot reference it from the schedule agent. I did reference the shared class library and can create an object of type myusercontrol but cannot access an image in that usercontrol for example I have an image control called backimage, and an object var control = myusercontrol(); I cannot call backimage using control.backimage.  any ideas?

Comment: Expose the child control (the Image) in a **public** property of your usercontrol: `public Image BackImage { get { return this.backimage; } }`